# How to convert Byte to String in Android USB Host?

Tags: android, serial-port, usb, usbserial

I have connected using pl2303 cable and trying to convert string from this method

```
  private void updateReceivedData(byte[] data) {
      String tmpString=HexDump.dumpHexString(data);
      // I've Tried several methods like 
      String dataString=new String(data);
      String dataString=new String(data,""UTF-8"");
      String dataString=Byte.decode(tmpString);
```

but none has helped. Kindly reply me.

Source :
[Method Link](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android/blob/master/usbSerialExamples/src/main/java/src/com/hoho/android/usbserial/examples/SerialConsoleActivity.java)

[Target Method[updateReceivedData(byte[] data)]](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android/blob/master/usbSerialForAndroid/src/main/java/com/hoho/android/usbserial/util/HexDump.java)

[Project Link](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android)

[Screenshot Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o2bot23x6r47tea/Screenshot_2014-08-28-17-27-30.png)

Comment: have you got the method **System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(byte[] Message)** available? Also, is the data definitely coming in as decimal (or hex data)?

Comment: @jbutler483 no it's in byte[].

Comment: change the **byte[] Message** from above to the name of your **byte[] array**

Comment: @jbutler483  Error: Text cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Comment: Have you included the namespace **using System.Text;**?

Comment: @jbutler483 yes... I'm afraid it's not available in java.lang.system package.

Comment: please see the edits in my answer

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using UTF8 encoding between string and byte[] (and vice versa).

This is done [in **c#**, but you should get the general idea :)] using;

```
using System.Text;    


public static String changeValue(byte[] msg)
{
String myMsg = "";
char[] msgAsChars = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(byte[] msg); 
//now should be a char array of your values

  for(int i=0;i<msgAsChars.Length;i++) 
  {
   //loop through your char array and add to string
    myMsg +=msgAsChars[i];
  }

return myMsg;
}
```

Might be a bit messy, but you should be able to get the idea.

**EDIT**

In java; decoding a byte array should be similar to:

```
String decoded = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

Or something like:

> to convert directly to String, you can always use
>
> ```
> `String str = new String(byte[] byteArray);`
> ```

**EDIT 2**

```
public class Main {

    /*
     * This method converts a byte array to a String object.
     */

    public void convertByteArrayToString() {

        byte[] byteArray = new byte[] {87, 79, 87, 46, 46, 46};

        String value = new String(byteArray);

        System.out.println(value);
    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().convertByteArrayToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: that looks like you are using the wrong baud rate (default is 9600)?

Comment: how are you monitoring your port? (to see these values coming in)?

Comment: My theory would be that there could be an error in how it's being 'saved' to text file (would a serial port monitor not be of better use?)

Answer (score 1):

First don't hard code your character Set

if your want to convert string to binary array, there is a special class know as Base64
from Apache Which is Open Source.

Add the following jar to your libs.
commons-codec-1.2.jar

try this:

```
byte[] decodeByteArray  = Base64.decodeBase64(data); //data is Source Byte Array from updateReceivedData method
String dataString  = new String(decodeByteArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your baud rate ? 
in  `sPort.setParameters(115200, 8, UsbSerialPort.STOPBITS_1, UsbSerialPort.PARITY_NONE);`

I was using the wrong baud rate and i changed from 115200 to 9600, then, in the updateReceivedData method, i used,  `String s = new String(data);`to convert the byte data into String.